# Python: modulos numpy y pandas

Tags: python

¿Alguien puede explicarme que hace este código?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Prueba.csv', sep=';')

numIteraciones = df.columns.size - 6

for i in range(1,numIteraciones+1):
    col = str(i)
    comando = df[col][0]
    registros = df.shape[0]-1
    aux = df[df[col]>=0]
```

No entiendo bien el `for` ni tampoco para que se usan las librerías pandas y numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es un poco complejo de explicar ya que supongo que resuelve un problema muy espécifico para los datos `Pruebas.csv` en concreto.

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) es una librería que permite trabajar con datos estructurados en filas y columnas (como una hoja de Excel). Creo que la mejor forma de imaginarse cúando trabajar con pandas es esa (si Excel se te queda pequeño).

[NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) es una librería fundamental de Python científico en la que se apoyan muchas otras (pandas incluído). Permite trabajar con datos como si fueran "matrices" (llamados arrays o arreglos) que se almacenan de forma eficiente en memoria. Si has usado MATLAB u GNU Octave, numpy es la librería que te permite trabajar de forma similar.

En el fragmento que has escrito sólo estás usando pandas, si te fijas no utiliza numpy (no aparece `np` en el código)

Te recomiendo que leas [este tutorial](https://github.com/Pybonacci/notebooks/blob/master/pandas_pymad_201405/Pandas_PyMAD_201405.ipynb) para entender mejor cómo trabajar con pandas.

En cualquier caso, te comento brevemente qué hace cada línea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# el intérprete de Python ignorará todo lo que siga a un '#'

# Hasta ahora hemos importado las librerías a las
# que accederemos de con el pseudonimo que hemos definido:
# 'pd' para pandas y 'np' para numpy.

df = pd.read_csv('Prueba.csv', sep=';')
# Aquí importamos los datos del archivo Prueba.csv
# CSV viene de comma separated value, por lo que el separador
# entre columnas es el ';'

# df significa data frame, que es el formato en el que trabaja pandas
# los data frame tienen filas y columnas tal y como si fueran una hoja de Excel

numIteraciones = df.columns.size - 6
# Aquí obtenemos el numero de iteraciones
# que será la cantidad de columnas menos 6 (nº arbitrario)

# En el siguiente bucle iremos desde el segundo elemento
# (recuerda que en Python los elementos empieza en 0)
# al último (ese +1 es para incluír el último)

for i in range(1,numIteraciones+1):
    # si no te ha quedado muy claro lo de arriba
    # puedes añadir un print(i) dentro del bucle para entenderlo

    col = str(i)
    # Aquí está cambiando el número i a un formato tipo string (cadena de texto)
    # Esto es  necesario para trabajar con los data frames. Como verás a continuación
    # en pandas los indíces para seleccionar contenido entran como texto (son las cabeceras o headers).
    # Las cabeceras de tu CSV se habrán nombrado por números
    # te recomiendo el siguiente comando para enteder que tienes en el DataFrame:
    # df.head

    comando = df[col][0]
    # Aquí está seleccionado el primer elemento de la columna con cabecera 'i' 
    # El primer elemento de la fila se selecciona con ese [0],


    registros = df.shape[0]-1
    # Aquí está obteniedo el nº de filas  'df.shape[0]' y restándole
    # la unidad para (supongo) no coger la primera de ellas que tiene los cabceros
    # más adelante

    aux = df[df[col]>=0]
    # Aquí hay dos operaciones. Primero está seleccionando los elementos de la columna 'i'
    # que són mayores o iguales que 0
    # Esto lo utiliza para almacenar en la variable auxiliar todos los elementos del dataframe
    # que cumplían esa condición
```